# Turn off Window Change on Hover in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, window-manager, window-focus

Was mucking around with OmniDazzle, and appropriately pressed every keyboard shortcut to see all the effects.

Unfortunately now, when I hover over 'another' window - it comes into focus without me invoking via a click.

Could someone please point me in the direction of what I changed?

Comment: Have you tried quitting it and starting it again? // Though I hope you solved it by now. Voting to close as too localized, it seems like a regular temporary malfunction.

Comment: VTC again, user has apparently given up on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the configure window and go to the Focal Point options. You can turn it off there.

Comment: What can I turn off ? - it's there as a shortcut - not using the hovering as the catalyst.

Here's what I see: http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/7785/screenshot20091005at154.png

Thank you.